# Of Portals & Worlds

Tags: riddle, wordplay

My first attempt at puzzling. Let's see how many of you figure out the right *angle*.

EDIT: Some small changes.

> A mere tool I am,  
> In a world so grown, 
> Yet here I am,
>   
> Taking you on.
>
> I'm a supporter 
> of things well known, 
> Without me, these
>   portals, 
> you would never call your own.
>
> And kid yourself not, 
> I am almost the same, 
> As when I say "The
>   fate of the world 
> depends on."
>
> Of what I am made, 
> Is the Swan's Song of Stars, 
> And it's
>   neighbors, 
> they may sound but 
> unattractive they are.

EDIT: Another clue, as I feel the above clues might prove to be insufficient, and something that I feel I may have insufficiently described:

> What I am made of that I mentioned, 
>  is an ingredient among a few, 
>  among its kind it lies, 
> an elemental country not new.

Who am I?

P.S.: This is TOO easy.

EDIT: Hint 1

> A fine, young lady once said two me: "Don't take it literally for what it is, dear. Magic is just Science we don't understand."

EDIT: Hint 2 - Now this is just giving it away..

> Those famous things I support, 
> Once spawned beings of such form, 
>  So formidable these off-springs, 
>  Rode this world's storms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you:

> A hinge

A mere tool I am,
In a world so grown,
Yet here I am,
Taking you on.

> A hinge is a simple tool.  Also it is angled, as was mentioned in the puzzle preface.

I'm a supporter
of things well known,
Without me, these portals,
you would never call your own.

> Doors

And kid yourself not,
I am almost the same,
As when I say "The fate of the world
depends on"

> Depends on = hinges on

Of which I am made,
Is the Swan's Song of Stars,
And it's neighbors,
they may sound but
unattractive they are.

> Hinges are typically made of brass, which is metal.
>  Swan's song of stars I believe refers to the fact that metals come from the remnant of stars.
>  Unattractive I believe refers to the fact that brass is not magnetic.

What I am made of that I mentioned,
is an ingredient among a few,
among its kind it lies,
an elemental country not new.

> I think this means that brass is made of copper and zinc, which are two among a few metals on the periodic table.

Those famous things I support,
Once spawned beings of such form,
So formidable these off-springs,
Rode this world's storms.

> Storm doors, which have springs.

Comment: Aaand congratulations! You sir/ma'am have solved the riddle. Although your interpretations differ a bit from mine (I may be wrong), the final answer is correct. Those that differ are:
Swansong of stars: Iron - The element post which thermonuclear fusion yields no surplus energy and the star is, for all intents & purposes, doomed. And instead of storm doors, I was referring to The Doors - Riders on the Storm. But for this time, let's just say the end does justify the means.

Comment: And about the neighbors, I was referring to Manganese, which sounds similar to Magnesium, and is often confused by laymen with Magnesium as the cause of magnetism. P.S. - Any reviews on my riddle?

Comment: @Meet Well, I didn't know if I had guessed it right because a lot of the clues were hard to interpret.  I'd say try to make the clues a little easier next time.  For example, I don't know how many people know that fact about stars and iron.

Answer (score 4):

Are you:

> Internet browser

A mere tool I am,
In a world so grown,
Yet here I am,
Taking you on.

> Well, I'm using a browser, a tool, right now, am I?

I'm a supporter
of things well known,
Without me, these portals,
you would never call your own.

> Wikipedia, Google, etc. are all sites, or portals, which support things well known. You can also create your own site, but without a browser you can't develop it and call it your own.

And kid yourself not,
I am almost the same,
As when I say "The fate of the world
depends on my name."

> In the recent arab spring [Facebook was used as a strong tool](http://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2011/09/so-was-facebook-responsible-for-the-arab-spring-after-all/244314/) to spread the voice of the protest, preferred to the controlled mainstream tools such as television and radio.

Of which I am made,
Is the Swan's Song of Stars,
And it's neighbors,
they may sound but
unattractive they are.

> No idea for the swan song, but the neighbours are the television and radio, which are "unattractive" for the young people (and also rely a lot on the sound).

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is not the right answer. I'll drop a hint if no answers come up by tomorrow this time. Good try though!  :)

Comment: I've made some refinements, and added another clue. See if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

This could be totally off-base, but I'll give it a shot and say that you are a:

> Keystone (in an arch), which is an angled stone, keeping other stones in place.

A mere tool I am,
In a world so grown,
Yet here I am,
Taking you on.

> A keystone is a wedge-shaped stone, the Wedge being one of the simple machines (mere tools) in our advanced world.  In this puzzle, the keystone is taking on all us adept puzzlers, though it is just a simple machine.

I'm a supporter
of things well known,
Without me, these portals,
you would never call your own.

> The keystone is the one piece of the arch that holds all the rest together, and many (though not all) arches can be in the form of doors, or "portals".  Without the keystone, these would not exist.

And kid yourself not,
I am almost the same,
As when I say "The fate of the world
depends on *my name*."

> This one stone is the arch is the key to making the arch stable.  Though it does not bear much of the actual load, the other stones depend on it to stay in place.

Of which I am made,
Is the Swan's Song of Stars,
And it's neighbors,
they may sound but
unattractive they are.

> Here's where I start grasping at straws... The keystone is a stone or rock, which is made from the same elements that stars are.  Then I get tangled in the syntax and can't determine if the neighbors are referring back to the keystone or to Of Which I Am Made.

What I am made of that I mentioned,
is an ingredient among a few,
among its kind it lies,
an elemental country not new.

> Rocks and stones are nothing new, neither are the elements present in the universe, as they are the foundation of everything.

Comment: You are on the right track, and just one alternative away from the answer. Now if you had only found the Italian, you'd have been closer.

Comment: I've added a new hint. Hopefully it'll be a lightning strike of realization.